# set dropdownlist based on value or text

Tags: jquery

how do i set my dropdownlist to an index based on the value or text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to select the dropdown index based on the value of text passed to it?

```
$("select option[value="+searchText+"]").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to selecting the option whose value is in a textbox?

```
$("#select1").val($("#text1").val());
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

to select the dropdownlist item by value or text, use this

```
//this is to set selected item by value
$('#dropDownList').val('setToNewValue');

//this is to select by text
var findText = $('#textBoxId').val();
$('#dropDownList option').
  filter(function () {return ($(this).text() == findText); })).
  attr('selected', 'selected');
```